# Parsing XML into Android Application

Tags: java, android, xml, parsing

I am trying to parse [this XML](http://www.meteo.si/uploads/probase/www/observ/surface/text/sl/observationAms_NOVA-GOR_BILJE_latest.xml) onto my Android Application. 
I read quite a few questions on parsing the XML here on stackoverflow, yet I am not sure how to handle a `for` loop everyone mentioned, in my case.

If someone would be nice enough to give me a working example for this case of XML, I'd be very grateful.

**THE EXAMPLE CODE I FOUND ON STACKOVERFLOW**

```
    try {
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = db.parse(*/Insert my URL/*);
        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

        NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName(*/What to write here in my case?/*);

        item = new TextView[nodeList.getLength()];
        for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
            Node node = nodeList.item(i);
            item[i] = new TextView(this);

            Element fstElmnt = (Element) node;
            NodeList itemList = fstElmnt.getElementsByTagName(*/What to write here in my case?/*);
            Element itemElement = (Element) itemList.item(0);
            itemList = itemElement.getChildNodes();
            item[i].setText("item = "
                            + ((Node) itemList.item(0)).getNodeValue());

            layout.addView(item[i]);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("XML Pasing Excpetion = " + e);
    }

    /** Set the layout view to display */
    setContentView(layout);
}
```

The above code is **NOT** an example that I am using. It's just what I found on the internet how to parse XML on Android App. But my XML seems more complex than the ussually posted ones here.

Comment: Could you give me a link or a brief explanation of how could I use the JSON here?
I know what JSON is, since I worked with it. But it confused me now, as I don't know how could I display that XML on my App using JSON.

Comment: You cannot use JSON here, my mistake. Here is a guide which seems easy enough to follow - http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-dom-parser/

Answer (score 0):

use XmlPullParser for parsing XML in your android application. It is very easy to use and pretty fast.

I use XmlPullParser in all my applications.

Follow this tutorial it has nice example on how to use XmlPullParser.

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidXML/article.html

Comment: Thanks you, will check the tutorial and hopefully manage to do it!